# Convert distributed minio backup to standalone

Tags: minio

I have a backup of a distributed minio server (e.g. everything's a `xl.meta` file) that I need to restore in standalone mode. I can't find any documentation for this; any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

There's actually none... When we migrated our Veeam secondary backup repository from MinIO to the more reliable solution we just copied all the content at the Veeam level creating extra mirrored backup repository and simply ditching MiniIO after that. Could you do the same with the business application "talking" to your MiniIO over S3? It would be the most straight-fwd way to move on.

Comment: Sadly there is no minio server… just the backup.

Comment: I wonder how to create a new distributed server (single node?) from the backup.